# use user input to fill dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm really new at this so I apologize if this is a silly question, I am trying to ask users for their first and last name to add to a list of dictionaries, when I execute the code, it asks for 3 sets, but only updates the first dictionary.. can't get any other solution to work, any help would be appreciated.

```
dlist = [
    {"first":"", "last":""},
    {'first':"", "last":""},
    {'first':"", "last":""}
]
for d in dlist:
    dlist[0].update({'first':input("please enter a first name: ")})
    dlist[0].update({'last':input("please enter a last name: ")})
for d in dlist:
    for i in d:
        print(d[i])
```

Comment: try replacing `dlist[0]` with `d`

Comment: See how you use 'enumerate' and replace 0 with the loop index

Comment: @balderman looking at that code it doesn't look like it would benefit from `enumerate`. Using `enumerate` and then accessing values with the index would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you always update the same dictionnary :

```py
for d in dlist:
    dlist[0].update({'first':input("please enter a first name: ")})
    dlist[0].update({'last':input("please enter a last name: ")})
    #     ^__ here you put 0
```

You could iterate over the indexes instead :

```py
for i in range(len(dlist)):
    dlist[i].update({'first':input("please enter a first name: ")})
    dlist[i].update({'last':input("please enter a last name: ")})
```

Or continue to iterate on the dict and use the elem instead:

```py
for elem in dlist:
    elem.update({'first':input("please enter a first name: ")})
    elem.update({'last':input("please enter a last name: ")})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code always update dlist[0] and other dictionary didn't change. The solution for the question is :

```py
for d in range( len(dlist)):
    dlist[d].update({'first':input("please enter a first name: ")})
    dlist[d].update({'last':input("please enter a last name: ")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here because you are doing `dlist[0]` every time, you are not changing anything but the first one, you should change `dlist[0]` to `d`.

```
dlist = [
    {"first":"", "last":""},
    {'first':"", "last":""},
    {'first':"", "last":""}
]
for d in dlist:
    d.update({'first':input("please enter a first name: ")})
    d.update({'last':input("please enter a last name: ")})
for d in dlist:
    for i in d:
        print(d[i])
```

here if the input was:

```
please enter a first name: John
please enter a last name: Smith
please enter a first name: Bob
please enter a last name: Johnson
please enter a first name: Jeff
please enter a last name: Bezos
```

the output would be:

```
John
Smith
Bob
Johnson
Jeff
Bezos
```

I hope this helped, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

So at first you don't need to define a list of people. Just simply create an empty list like this

```
people = []
```

Then create a for loop of 3 repetitions where you will ask a user for a first name and last name

```
for i in range(3):
    firstName = str(input("Enter first name: "))
    lastName = str(input("Enter last name: "))
```

Then you need to append first name and last name into list as dict.

```
people.append({
        "first": firstName,
        "last": lastName
    })
```

At the end just simply print it by iterating through a list of dictionaries. I prefer printing with [f-string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

```
for person in people:
    print(f"{person['first']} {person['last']}")
```

Full example code here

```
people = []

for i in range(3):
    firstName = str(input("Enter first name: "))
    lastName = str(input("Enter last name: "))

    people.append({
        "first": firstName,
        "last": lastName
    })

    print()    # Just print new line for esthetic purpose only

for person in people:
    print(f"{person['first']} {person['last']}")
```

I suggest you to learn it carefully and of not skip any part of tutorial.

## Useful links

- [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)
- [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
- [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)